# Polar coordinate of a circle.

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

If I have a circle of radius $a$ center at $(a,0)$.
If I want to change coordinate from Cartesian coordinate to polar coordinate. I have convinced myself that $r=2a\cos\theta$ and $\frac{-\pi}{2}\le\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$.

But what if a circle of radius $a$ center at $(0,a)$?
I know that $r=2a\sin\theta$ but why $0\le\theta<\pi?$ Looking at the graph it seems like $\theta$ can vary from $-\pi$ to $\pi.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second circle is in the upper-half plane.  Also, the angle parametrizing the first circle ranged over $\pi$ radians.  Why would the second be any different?

Actually, any interval of length $\pi$ seems to work!

The first circle can be parametrized as:

$$r=2a\cos\theta \text{ and }\phi_0\le\theta<\phi_0+\pi,$$  and the second as

$$r=2a\sin\theta \text{ and }\phi_0\le\theta<\phi_0+\pi,$$

for any $\phi_0.$

Comment: thanks, I got it.

Comment: You are welcome.